# For each text you find, set a class

Tags: jquery

I have a div, and an div inside containing text. Based on that text I want to set another class with the .page-slider-text

```
<div class="page-slider-text">
   <div class="farbschema-front">Light</div>
</div>

<div class="page-slider-text">
  <div class="farbschema-front">Dark</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.page-slider-text').filter(function () {
   return $('.farbschema-front:contains("Light")');
}).addClass('light');

$('.page-slider-text').filter(function () {
   return $('.farbschema-front:contains("Dark")');
}).addClass('dark');
```

It works, with the problem that .page-slider-text gets the light and dark class and not based not the one that fits inside the matching div.

The possibility that there is something wrong with my thoughts is very likely.

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code to deal with both elements in a single call to `addClass()` which sets the class based on the text of the child `.farbschema-front` element. Try this:

```js
$('.page-slider-text').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).find('.farbschema-front').text().toLowerCase();
});
```

```css
.light {
  color: #DDD;
}
.dark {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-slider-text">
  <div class="farbschema-front">Light</div>
</div>

<div class="page-slider-text">
  <div class="farbschema-front">Dark</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` function accepts either true or false for filtering items.
jQuery always returns an object which is truthy.
It means that this code actually does nothing:

```
.filter(function () {
    return $('.farbschema-front:contains("Light")');
})
```

If you want to check if child item has `Light` or `Dark`, you can do the following:

```js
 $('.page-slider-text').filter(function() {
   return $(this).find('.farbschema-front:contains("Light")').length > 0;
 }).addClass('light');

 $('.page-slider-text').filter(function() {
   return $(this).find('.farbschema-front:contains("Dark")').length > 0;
 }).addClass('dark');
```

```css
.light {
  color: #DDD;
}
.dark {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-slider-text">
  <div class="farbschema-front">Light</div>
</div>

<div class="page-slider-text">
  <div class="farbschema-front">Dark</div>
</div>
```

This code tells "find all 'page-slider-text' items. now, take only those which have at least one child element 'farbschema-front' containing 'Dark'. add class 'dark' to such elements".

However, there is a shorter way to do this:

```js
$('.page-slider-text > .farbschema-front:contains("Dark")').parent().addClass("dark");
$('.page-slider-text > .farbschema-front:contains("Light")').parent().addClass("light");
```

```css
.light {
  color: #DDD;
}
.dark {
  color: #666;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-slider-text">
  <div class="farbschema-front">Light</div>
</div>

<div class="page-slider-text">
  <div class="farbschema-front">Dark</div>
</div>
```

which means "find all 'farbschema-front' elements having 'Dark' as a text, which are children of 'page-slider-text' element. now, take their parent (which is 'page-slider-text') and add a class 'dark'".